# VBA IE.document Click

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

The HTML code is as followed on a webpage. It's a link that I want to be able to click on from VBA.

```html
<a title="View Account Summary" class="unregLink" href="/Standard/AccountSummary/Pages/default.aspx">View Account Summary</a>​
```

It doesn't have an ID, Name, etc. How can I get VBA (IE.document) to click on the link?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have a distinguishable parent element that you could use?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `querySelector`. Othervise you will need some parent as @TheSilkCode proposed in the comment. HTH

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Set doc = ie.document
Dim htmlAnchor As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement
Set htmlAnchor = doc.querySelector("a[class='unregLink'][href='/Standard/AccountSummary/Pages/default.aspx']")
htmlAnchor.click
```